# Difficulty aligning checkboxes in CSS

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty lining up my checkboxes (under **Weeks**) with the other sections of my form (namely **2. Date & Time**). In addition to this, I can't seem to get text to the right of the checkbox, it always seeems to appear underneath. How can I resolve this?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4YMaQ/2/

**Code**

```
label {
    width: 8em;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
select {
    width: 70%;
}
.slider, .slider2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
input {
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', arial, helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.w50 {
    width: 50%;
}
.weeks fieldset {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.weeks fieldset > legend {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3.8em;
}
.weeks fieldset .item {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.weeks fieldset label {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    outline: none;
}
fieldset span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12em;
}
.weeks fieldset span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
}
.request_heading {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.page {
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: @John that would not be Valid.

Comment: O, he is using float... tut :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spans are 2em (you seem to have overwritten your 12em on the line below) where as your labels are 8em which is why they are wrapping onto the next line if you change your

if you change your spans to 3.5em and your labels to 1.5em you will get the following:

```
 .weeks fieldset label {width:1.5em}
 .weeks fieldset span {width:3em;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4YMaQ/6/

if you change your right margin on your legend you can fit five on a line:

```
 .weeks fieldset > legend {margin-right:1.1em;}
```

Comment: This. Also, checkboxes will have a default margin in some browsers (including Chrome). So you might want to rest/explicitly define that.

Comment: Thanks @Pete, it works fantastically - how do I resolve this issue tho http://imgur.com/ZcDkgDI

Comment: what's the issue? if it is the wrong amount of numbers on each line then just play with the left margin of your legend as shown above

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the width of the .weeks fieldset, you force the checkboxes to go under weeks :)

```
.weeks fieldset {
border: none;
outline: none;
width: 50px;
}
```

It did not work anymore because other things changed, this is what you have to do:

```
.weeks fieldset .item {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 40px;
}
```

Remove overflow hidden and add a width to this field.

```
.weeks fieldset {
border: none;
outline: none;
width: 124px;
```

}

The width i provided might not be the width you want, adjust to your own needs :)

Comment: I've tried it and it just makes the .weeks fieldset disappear - http://jsfiddle.net/4YMaQ/9/

Comment: Change it back to the way it was and let me take another look, it worked fine for me just a second ago

Comment: If people keep updating the Fiddle the working code I gave you won't ever work ;)

Comment: When you update a Fiddle, it creates another revision of it, so the version you're on isn't modified.

Answer (score 1):

**Now just define** your class  `.weeks fieldset span` `text-align:center;` and

**Define** your `.weeks fieldset label` `with:auto;`

**as like this**

```
.weeks fieldset span{
    text-align:center;    
}
.weeks fieldset label{
    width:auto;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4YMaQ/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

I changed the structure of your HTML to match your needs, I removed all the `labels` after the `inputs`.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/EwRxf/1/), let me know if it's good enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just Use `display: inline-block;` to your `item class` It works. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4YMaQ/13/)**

Answer (score 1):

Changing the display of your .item-Elements to `inline-block` should do the trick.

```
.weeks fieldset .item {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```